# How to disable the back button on android with Apache Cordova?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

sorry for any spelling mistakes as english is not my first language.

So, to the question:

I am making an android app using jquery mobile and Apache Cordova, both in the latest versions, so the question is:

Is there a way i can disable the back button on the android phone when in the app?

Comment: $('#backBtn').attr('disabled',true)

#backBtn will be your back button id or any identifier

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        // appView.loadUrl("javascript: clickBack()");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but im kinda of a noob in Cordova, but i think in Cordova you dont work with Activities like with Android Studio, so can you make clear where should i put this?

Comment: when you build your app for Android, you will find following path:
platforms/android/src/path/to/your/projectname/MainActivity.java

Whatever you write inside MainActivity.java, will be compiled to your apk file. You can add the code I provided into MainActivity class.

Answer (score 0):

you can handle backbutton like this

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown() {
    // Handle the back button
}
```

so its not going to close whatever you are going to do i think